# put dynamic value in $_POST

Tags: php, post, dynamic

I want to use a code like

```
foreach($_POST[cat_id] as $key=>$val){
                if($val){
                $arr[cat_id] = $val;
                $arr[porder] = $_POST['".$val."'];
                $arr[store_user_id] =$_SESSION[uid];        
                }
            }
```

but `$_POST['".$val."']` will not cover any value but in my loop put the name dynamically can any one help me I want to show value of `$_POST['".$val."']` which comes dynamically. I also use `$_POST['<?=$val?>']` but it does not work.. please help...

Comment: What about just simply `$_POST[$val]`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$_POST[$val]` in place of `$_POST['".$val."']`

Comment: Its the same what I have there

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this way:

```
$arr[cat_id] = $_POST[$val]
```

?